# Import JSON into Heroku Rails app then store in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, postgresql, heroku, import

I have a Rails 3.2 Application that is hosted on Heroku.
I would like to try and avoid manually entering all of the data for each
new record. Is their an easy way for me to get my rails app to look at a
JSON file like this (except MUCH LARGER) and parse that information into
the database?

```
[   {
    "name": "Sierra Mist – Small Cup",
    "wwpplus": "5",
    "ssize": "451g",
    "calories": "190",
    "tfat": "0",
    "protein": "0",
    "fiber": "0",
    "carbs": "50",
    "restaurant_id": "12"
},
{
    "name": "Vanilla Shake regular",
    "wwpplus": "13",
    "ssize": "425g",
    "calories": "480",
    "tfat": "15",
    "protein": "14",
    "fiber": "0",
    "carbs": "74",
    "restaurant_id": "12"
},
{
    "name": "Vanilla Shake small",
    "wwpplus": "11",
    "ssize": "340g",
    "calories": "380",
    "tfat": "12",
    "protein": "11",
    "fiber": "0",
    "carbs": "60",
    "restaurant_id": "12"
}]
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could parse it in your `db/seeds.rb` file:

```
records = JSON.parse(File.read('path/to/file.json'))
records.each do |record|
  ModelName.create!(record)
end
```

Then `heroku run rake db:seed`

Comment: I had no idea rails could do that

Just added JSON GEM

Added those lines to my seed file

rake db:seed

Boom 127 records added THANKS MAN